# Inure: are there degrees of inurement?

Tags: meaning

Is it correct to write that someone is MORE inured to something? The question is, are there degrees of inure - can you be more, or less inured?

Answer (score 3):

The participial adjective, "[inured](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/inured)", is gradable; numerous examples of the sort shown below can be found.

[St Kilda: A People's History - Roger Hutchinson · 2014](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/St_Kilda/z5y8BQAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22more+or+less+inured%22&pg=PT59&printsec=frontcover) It is very probable that the atmosphere in St Kilda is free from a number of disease-causing organisms, which are rife in other parts, where the inhabitants are more or less inured to them.

[Delphi Collected Works of Martin Luther (Illustrated) - Martin Luther, ‎ Delphi Classics · 2017](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Delphi_Collected_Works_of_Martin_Luther/CrbADwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22more+inured+than%22&pg=PA3706&printsec=frontcover) That, in those days, people were more inured than our refined contemporaries to the controversial use of such revolting coarseness has been stated and is indeed perfectly true.

[Friarswood Post-office - Charlotte Mary Yonge · 1874](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Friarswood_Post_office/gDvaHFYNcm0C?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22less+inured+to%22&pg=PA157&printsec=frontcover) and, used to good shelter and regular meals, he was less inured to bodily hardship than many a cottage boy.

It is  clear that the verb itself has a degree argument (
[Verbal gradability and degree arguments in verbs University of Pennsylvania
PDF -
INTRODUCTION AND DATA](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/Events/PLC/plc37/abstracts/Anderson_PLC37.pdf)), but, very apparently, it is not used in this way. The following ngram shows that no nouns and pronouns appear in the usual constructions indicating a degree.

[inured * more,inured * less,inured the * more,inures * more,inures * less,inures the * more](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inured+%28*%29+more%2Cinured+*+less%2Cinured+the+*+more%2Cinures+*+more%2Cinures+*+less%2Cinures+the+*+more&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Constructions in which  "verb + them" and the adverb "more" are separated by an arbitraryly long sequence of words do not exist either.

- [inures them … more](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_eng&tbs=lr%3Alang_1fr&tbm=bks&q=%22inures%22+%22them%22+%22more%22)

Evident logic shows that  what is true for the adjective should also be true for the verb or vice versa. For instance the third example above should, apparently, elicit the following sentence.

- ? and good shelter and regular meals had inured him to bodily hardship less
  than many a cottage boy.

But this is not so, the native reader will probably find that this sentence borders on unidiomaticity or be unsure.

The noun "inurement" can be used with "greater", for instance, and is therefore usable in degrees ([greater, inurement](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%22greater%22%22inurement%22#ip=1)).

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can be.**

To be inured to something means that you're so familiar to something that you don't notice it anymore. And people can be more familiar with things than others.

For example, say there's a person that's been farming the exact same crop for 10 years. They would be much more familiar with farming than someone who's only been farming for 3.

Let's have another example. Someone has been living in the same house with the same photos in the same photos for 10 years. Someone new comes to the house. They, as a result of not being familiar with the photos, would likely notice them more than the person who's seen them every day for 10 years, who wouldn't notice them very much at all (they are much more *inured* to it).